# No funciona Método de insercion Directa | Visual Basic

Tags: vba

no funciona este código, se queda trabado cada vez que quieres dar al botón de "ordenar" , los siguientes variables están declaradas como,  i, j, Auxiliar, n  como de valor entero. El código es el siguiente:

```
If rbdirecto.Checked = True Then
    n = lstnumeros.Items.Count
    For i = 1 To n
        Auxiliar = lstnumeros.Items(i)
        j = i - 1

        While (j >= 0) And (Auxiliar < lstnumeros.Items(j))
            lstnumeros.Items(j + 1) = lstnumeros.Items(j)
            j = j - 1
        End While
    lstnumeros.Items(j + 1) = Auxiliar
    Next
End If
```

Sería de mucha ayuda que me digan en donde esta el error del codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré dos cosas en tu código: un es que el For debería ir de cero a N-1, ya que no es un vector, sino una lista que comienza de cero.  Lo segundo es que el While en lugar de tener un And debería tener un AndAlso, para que en caso de que j sea menor a cero no de error la segunda validación del while.
Te paso el código:

```
If rbdirecto.Checked = True Then
    n = lstnumeros.Items.Count
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Auxiliar = lstnumeros.Items(i)
        j = i - 1

        While (j >= 0) AndAlso (Auxiliar < lstnumeros.Items(j))
            lstnumeros.Items(j + 1) = lstnumeros.Items(j)
            j = j - 1
        End While
    lstnumeros.Items(j + 1) = Auxiliar
    Next
End If
```

Espero te sirva.
¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, me salvaste el c*lo ! :)